# Makemigrations and migrate in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem in the **Django**

For example:

**In Definition of models. i have :**

```
class Social_Network(models.Model):
    Name      = models.TextField(null=False)
    Addresses = models.TextField(null=False)
```

**And after running**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Until this part everything its ok

My problem is starting now. When i want to change (Social_Network) models.

```
class Social_Network(models.Model):
    Id        = models.TextField(null=False)
    Name      = models.TextField(null=False)
    Addresses = models.TextField(null=False)
```

I inserted 'Id' to 'social network' models

**And after running**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I encounter the following error

[image]

Please Help me

Comment: Did you have a trailing comma at the end of the `Id=...` line?

Comment: Django Models when used to create tables will have a default primary key for every table that is id. thats the reason your migration does not get applied, as there is already a field id in the social_network table. if you want to update the default primary key  to the Id yu mentioned use -- Id        = models.TextField(null=False, primary_key=True) or instead of Id use some other name.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, each model has an AutoField named **id** by default unless you explicitly specify *primary_key=True* on a field in your model. See the documentation for [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) for more details.